# Filter menu icons on search page, left or right of menu item?

Tags: layout

Curious what people's thoughts are for filter menu dropdown icons, should they go on the left or right side?

My thinking is the icon provides a buffer between the dropdown menu text and the search results.

The layout is fairly standard, but if there are other critiques I'm open to them as well.

Thank you!

[image: search page template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but I would say an icon on the left of the label is used for clarification rather than an action in itself. An icon on the right would trigger an action:

[image]

Now, should the label trigger the action?

- If yes then including the icon on the left is the way to go
- If no then leaving the icon on the right might be best as it is a button in itself

---

[Material design - Lists](https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists.html#lists-content)